# php timezone not matching with current time on server

Tags: php

i am using following codes to get current time on server as per timezone parameter but i am getting wrong output. About 10/20 minutes delay then server time. And it also not gets updated. How to solve it? any idea?

```
<?php

function server_time_as_per_users_zone($users_zone){
  $dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($users_zone));
  $r = $dateTime->format("d-m-Y h:m A");
  return $r;
}

echo server_time_as_per_users_zone("Asia/Dhaka");
```

Comment: Have you checked your servers original time is okay? :)  I think this script perfect, the problem is with your input

Comment: its now on my local windows 10 pc with Xampp server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong format mask. The `m` stands for month number and not minutes.

Change it to

```
function server_time_as_per_users_zone($users_zone){
    $dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($users_zone));
    $r = $dateTime->format("d-m-Y h:i A");
    return $r;
}

echo 'UTC           - ' . server_time_as_per_users_zone("UTC").PHP_EOL;
echo 'Europe/London - ' . server_time_as_per_users_zone("Europe/London").PHP_EOL;
echo 'Asia/Dhaka    - ' . server_time_as_per_users_zone("Asia/Dhaka").PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT:

```
UTC           - 19-04-2017 05:40:23 PM
Europe/London - 19-04-2017 06:40:23 PM
Asia/Dhaka    - 19-04-2017 11:40:23 PM
```

Comment: That's why u r 52K. Thanks a lot bro!